# C# running batch file on remote machine after PsExec has been started

Tags: c#, file, batch-file, psexec

Basically, I'm trying to run the batch file that was copied on the remote machine, by the way, this is my first attempt at coding, so please be nice but critique it if you want, I'm still learning the language and had to spend 3 hours to get this far, thank god for Google, LOL.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void cleanerBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Copying Batch File to Remote Host
            string fileToCopy = "C:\\Clean.bat";
            string newLocation = hostName.Text;
            string newFile = (newLocation + "\\clean.bat");

            System.IO.File.Copy(fileToCopy, newLocation);

            //Run PsExec
            string psExec = "psexec -s "+newLocation+" cmd";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", psExec);

            //Run Batch File using PsExec


            //Removing Batch File from Remote Host
            System.IO.File.Delete(newFile);

        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for a good attitude. Wish I knew psexec so I could help you.

Comment: Suggestion for style: you could add `using SystemDiagnostics;` and `using System.IO;` at the top and just use `Process.Start("CMD.exe", psExec);`, `File.Copy(fileToCopy, newLocation);` `File.Delete(newFile);` afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From PSExec help:

-c         Copy the specified program to the remote system for
           execution. If you omit this option the application
           must be in the system path on the remote system.

Use that flag to make PSExec copy the batch file that you want executed to the remote system and run it. You don't have to write extra code to do that.

Basically you want to do:

```
psexec \\server cmd.exe /c file_you_want_to_run.bat
```

Comment: This is correct. You may have to use the username/password flags of psexec, but you don't need to write any of your own code to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try running CMD.exe with /C. From cmd.exe help:

> /C Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates

The /C needs to be appended to the content of the psExec:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/C " + psExec);
```

I believe you'll get the expected results then. If not, you might want to make sure `psexec.exe` is in a directory that is in the PATH environment variable.

Also, you might be interested to look into [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) to specify different other parameters that can be set for the execution of a process.

Comment: i really appreciate all of your answers, for the \\run batch file using psexec portion, how would i get it to execute a batch file that was copied to the remote machine (string hostName)?

Comment: I don't think you can execute code on a foreign machine. You can execute the batch file from the network machine on yours, but not the other way around. That would be a serious security flaw.